# Which is better to select IDs of updated data: Join with Temp table or using OUTPUT INTO?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-server-2016

I want to select IDs of updated data and return them to client. which way is better?

1- **using OUTPUT INTO**:

```
DECLARE @TempE TABLE (  
    Id BIGINT NOT NULL,    
    Token VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL
);

UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
   SET [State] = 3  -- Expired
OUTPUT Deleted.[Id], Deleted.[Token]
  INTO @TempE
 WHERE [ExpireDate] < GETDATEUTC();

SELECT Id,
       Token
FROM @TempE;
```

2- **using a temp table, update with join**:

```
SELECT 
    [E].[Id],
    [E].[Token]
INTO #tempTb
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE [ExpireDate] < GETUTCDATE();

UPDATE [M]
SET [M].[State] = 3 -- Expired
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [M]
INNER JOIN #tempTb AS [T] ON [T].[Id] = [M].[Id];

SELECT Id,
       Token
FROM #tempTb;
```

The server is SQL Server 2016, and no more than 500 rows are expected to be updated in each execution.

thanks for any help :)

Comment: Why use a table variable/temporary table at all and not just `OUTPUT` without an `INTO`?

Comment: @Larnu Thanks, i am not aware of such thing. but the question is still valid. `OUTPUT` or temp table? which one has better performance? i can read your comment as "`OUTPUT` is better". am i right?

Comment: Keep in mind that you may need to wrap a transaction around multiple statements in order to ensure the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in the comment, there's no need for a table variable/temporary table here, just `OUTPUT` the result set:

```sql
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
   SET [State] = 3  -- Expired
OUTPUT inserted.[Id], inserted.[Token]
 WHERE [ExpireDate] < GETDATEUTC();
```

Also, personally, I would use `inserted` here, not `deleted`, though they *should* be semantically the same for this scenario (unless you have a trigger of something effecting the values of `Token` or `Id` in an `UPDATE`).